# Scrapyd 404 error to run curl http://localhost:6800/daemonstatus.json

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to check the load status of service and runing curl                              http://localhost:6800/daemonstatus.json the server responded with a 
status of 404 (No Such Resource). please help

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. And it turns out it is the inconsistency between the Scrapyd document and the scrapyd distribution.

The `daemonstatus.json` is added after Scrapyd 1.1.0. (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/commit/2fa5513083d0307ac6a0dcb06f5c82669e464175#diff-d122517454dbd6aa38b4726d1ba9e267)

So, if you want the daemonstatus API, you will need to use the `master` branch https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/tree/master. And install it via `python setup.py install`. Before you install the `master` branch, remember to uninstall the old version that you installed via `pip install scrapyd`.